# How many ways are there to characterise $\mathbb{P}^n$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry, projective-geometry

Let $\mathbb{P}^n$ denote the complex projective space of dimension $n$. In many respects, this is the *model* of (positivity in) complex geometry. There are some well-known characterisations of $\mathbb{P}^n$:

1. (Most standard characterisation?) $\mathbb{P}^n$ is the parameter space of complex lines through the origin in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$.
2. (Kobayashi-Ochiai). $\mathbb{P}^n$ is the unique compact Kähler manifold $X$ whose first Chern class is $\lambda c_1(\mathscr{F})$, where $\lambda \geq 1+\dim_{\mathbb{C}}(X)$ and $\mathscr{F}$ is a positive line bundle on $X$.
3. (Mori, Siu-Yau). $\mathbb{P}^n$ is the unique compact Kähler manifold $X$ with a Kähler metric of positive bisectional curvature (this, in fact, characterises $\mathbb{P}^n$ *with the Fubini-Study metric*, since the biholomorphism here is also an isometry.

In contrast with spheres, $\mathbb{P}^n$ does not appear to be characterised by the sectional curvature of a Riemannian metric on it. Indeed, by the well-known $\frac{1}{4}$-pinching theorem, a compact Riemannian manifold with a Riemannian metric whose sectional curvature $K$ is pinched $\frac{1}{4} < K \leq 1$ is diffeomorphic to a sphere.

Of course, the Fubini-Study metric on $\mathbb{P}^n$ has sectional curvature pinched by $\frac{1}{4} \leq K \leq 1$, but this does characterise $\mathbb{P}^n$ at all: spheres, the Quaternionic projective space, and the Fake Cayley plane  also possess metrics with sectional curvature pinched between $\frac{1}{4} \leq K \leq 1$.

I'm very interested in the following question:

> What other characterisations of $\mathbb{P}^n$ exist in the literature?

Additionally:

> In particular, are there purely Riemannian characterisations of $\mathbb{P}^n$?

Comment: Why isn't this a purely Riemannian characterization?  Take the canonical circle bundle over the manifold that kills the $2^{nd}$ homotopy group, this is an odd-dimensional sphere and the projective space has the Riemann metric of that quotient space.  This is just the higher version of talking about covering spaces of manifolds with $+1$ sectional curvature.  You've just replaced covering spaces (i.e. discrete bundles) with circle bundles.

Comment: There is also the characterization by Cho, Miyaoka, and Shepherd-Barron: the unique Fano $n$-fold with Fano pseudoindex equal to $n+1$.

Comment: Though you seem to be more interested by differential-geometric characterizations, let me mention that there are many such characterizations in algebraic geometry: see *Cohomological characterizations of projective spaces and hyperquadrics* by
Araujo-Druel-Kovács (Invent. Math. 174 (2008), no. 2, 233–253), and in particular the introduction.

Comment: It seems like the Seshadri constant of the anticanonical at a smooth point also gives a characterization: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00209-017-1941-9

Comment: For a somewhat different Riemannian characterisation the  Blaschke Conjecture may interest you. 

**Definition:** A Riemannian manifold of diameter $d$ is called  Blaschke  if every geodisic from any point of length less than $d$ is the unique shortest path between any two points on it.

The Blaschke conjecture states that  a manifold satisfying the  Blaschke condition is isometric to a compact rank 1 symmetric space.

Comment: If the  Blaschke Conjecture is true then the only Riemannian manifolds satisfying this condition also having an almost complex structure (without any compatibility condition with the metric) are  $\mathbb{CP}^n$ (with the Fubini-Study metric) and  $S^6$ (with the round metric). 

If one requires that the metric is Kahler then the exceptional case $S^6$ dissapears.

The Blaschke Conjecture is known up to diffeomorphism for complex projective spaces and up to isometry for spheres. Searching "Blaschke Conjecture " should yield the relevant references,